# Trigger Function When Component is Resized in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, responsive

I'm working in an Angular project. I have a component that has responsive functionality. We have logic setup so that we perform the needed responsive functionality whenever the window resizes. We use this to achieve that:

```
@HostListener("window:resize", ["$event"])
onResize(): void { ... }
```

That works great when the window sizes changes. However, now we've added a side panel to the page that can be collapsed. We want to perform the responsive functionality when the panel is expanded/collapsed. Or in other words, **we want to perform our responsive logic when the size of the    component changes, even if the window size is the same.**

How can we achieve this?

Comment: I don't think there is any easy built-in method, as an element resize doesn't trigger a DOM event, unlike the window resize. But you could try out [Resize Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver).

Comment: What about a sidePanelService, which hosts a subject, to which your component subscribe to know when it toggles ?

Comment: @Random I'd like to have it more supportive than that. I don't want the responsive component to need knowledge of other elements on the page, it should simply be responsive within it's given space.

Comment: well, your component is already using `@HostListener("window:resize", ["$event"])`, so your component is checking for a resize event. The logic is already there. But what you could do also, is a "resizeService", which triggers an event when the window resize, and when the sidebar toggles. So your component would only subscribe to one event, and doesn't have to know who triggers it

Comment: @Random the responsive component is a shared component, used in multiple other applications. I don't think requiring all apps to setup a 'resizeService' in order to use our component would be ideal. Looking for the component itself to keep track of this.

Comment: I'm fairly certain you can just shove `(resize)="onElementResized()"` as an event on whatever div you desire - so, like, the outer-most div of your side panel?